# ABAddressBookSave taking a very long time

Tags: ios, time, abaddressbook

I am trying to save the unsaved contacts through **ABAddressBook** using the following code:

```
CFErrorRef error = NULL;
if (ABAddressBookHasUnsavedChanges(addressBook)) {
    ABAddressBookSave(addressBook, &error);
} else {
    ABAddressBookRevert(addressBook);
}
```

If I try to save about 1000 contacts, it is taking more than one minute to perform the action. I have run the code in *Time Profiler* and it reports 92% of total time elapsed singly on **ABAddressBookSave**.

Please help me reduce the time complexity of my code.

Comment: Yes I have the same question.Do you solve the problem?

Comment: I have put whole addressbook access and saving functionality of my application on different thread(i.e. dispatch_queue_async{}).So some performance is enhanced. Also logged an issue with apple developer and getting same response to use dispatch_queue, after one month of request. Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have put whole addressbook access and saving functionality of my application on different thread(i.e. dispatch_queue_async{}).So some performance is enhanced. Also logged an issue with apple developer and getting same response to use dispatch_queue, after one month of request. Hope it will help you! –